# Yii2 Links between Frontend and Backend (advanced template)

Tags: php, yii2

If i need add links to frontend stuff from backend part in menu(or from backend to admin), how i can do this without hardcode?
This:

```
 \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl
```

returns path from parents dir

```
/sitename/backend/web
/sitename/frontend/web
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your backend application config you should add additional 'UrlManager' component with different name and configuration equals to the one used at front end application:

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            // here is your backend URL rules
        ],
        'urlManagerFrontEnd' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
            'baseUrl' => '/a/frontend/web',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],

    ],
];
```

Then you should invoke following to compose front-end URL:

```
Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->createUrl();
```

Comment: So, it must looks something like this?

$menuItems = [
   ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
   ['label' => 'Frontend', 'url' => [Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->createUrl('/')]],
];

Comment: yes but this Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->createUrl('/') returned  in forntend path  but you need set in create url for example Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->createUrl('controllerName/ActionName
')

Comment: Sadly, but it works only if im put this in link
<a href="<?=Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->baseUrl ?>">Frontend</a>
But not works in navbar NavBar::begin([...

I got this if i use it in navbar:
Unable to resolve the request "sitename/frontend/web".
Perhaps Navbar add old baseurl to request.

Comment: This code not created <a href></a> this return backend url

Answer (score 3):

My mistake - I was incorrectly sent link value.

Wrong:

```
$menuItems[] = ['label'=>'frontend', 'url'=>[\Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->baseUrl]];
```

Thats Works:

```
$menuItems[] = ['label'=>'frontend', 'url'=>\Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->baseUrl];
```