# Yii2 Link FrontEnd To BackEnd

Tags: yii2

How to link from frontend page to backend in Yii2 using advanced template.... I want to link the login button from frondend to backend...when I click on login button in frontend it can redirect to login page in backend that I already created...

```
<div class="wrap">
    <?php
        NavBar::begin([
            'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
            'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
            ],
        ]);
        $menuItems = [
                ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
                ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
                ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
        ];
        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Signup', 'url' => ['/site/signup']];
            $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']];
        } else {
            $menuItems[] = [
                'label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                'url' => ['/site/logout'],
                'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
            ];
        }
        echo Nav::widget([
            'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
            'items' => $menuItems,
        ]);
        NavBar::end();
    ?>

    <div class="container">
        <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
            'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
        ]) ?>
        <?= Alert::widget() ?>
        <?= $content ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Please can you include the code from your `login` action in your site controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 Links between Frontend and Backend (advanced template)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206370/yii2-links-between-frontend-and-backend-advanced-template)

Comment: @JoeMiller: here my login action in backend/site/controller: public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

Comment: In that case your question is answered in the question @arogachev posted above.

Comment: @zack Update question with this info instead of writing code as comment, also without formatting it's hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a relative path

```
 if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
 $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Signup', 'url' => ['/site/signup']];

 $menuItems[] = ['label' =>'Login','url' =>'../../../backend/site/login'];
    } else {
```

add this in common/config/main.php 
under the section components

```
'components' => [
    .....
    'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
            'showScriptName' => true, 
    ],
    .......
```

Comment: i got eror : Not found (#404)

Comment: Which you are using..?

Comment: this link from my frontend : http://localhost/testSystem/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Findex  then this from my backend http://localhost/testSystem/backend/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogin

Comment: I'm sorry but  are you suer  you have an action login in the backend Site Controller and a login view in backend/views/site ?

Comment: yes i sure.....actually i use default site controller that provide from yii2 framework..

Comment: after your code in frontend ..i got this url: http://localhost/testSystem/frontend/web/index.php?r=..%2F..%2F..%2Fbackend%2Fweb%2Findex.php%3Fr%3Dsite%26login

Comment: I have update the second one (@backend) removing the external [] try this way

Comment: and same hover link? ... show me you config/main.php   frontend, common, and backend components / urlManager

Comment: same hover...and same config/main.php in advanced template..i can't copy on this because it's too long

Comment: show just one only the section utlManager in section components (config/main.php)

Comment: i already add url manger in common/config/main.php but get same eror..http://localhost/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=C%3A%5Cxampp%5Chtdocs%5Cadvanced%2Fbackend%2Fsite%2Flogin

Comment: I have update the answer .. try the first one  ('../../..' )

Comment: http://localhost/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=C%3A%5Cxampp%5Chtdocs%5Cadvanced%2Fbackend%2Fsite%2Flogin

Comment: I have update the answer .. try this way and  comment  me the hover link

Comment: This looks like a hack, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206370/yii2-links-between-frontend-and-backend-advanced-template) is a recommended way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

add to section components after urlManager in frontend/config/main.php

```
'urlManagerBackend' => [
     'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
     'baseUrl' => 'http://backend.site.local',
     'hostInfo' => 'http://backend.site.local',
     'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
     'enableStrictParsing' => true,
     'showScriptName' => false,
     ],
```

in frontend/views/layout

add something like this

```
$menuItems = [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => 'Admin panel', 'url' =>  Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createUrl([''])],
    ];
```