# Yii2 show image in backend from frontend - settting alias

Tags: php, image, yii2, aliases

In my project I used an image cropper widget. I setup the widget, that it save in frontend/web/upload. But in backend I save the images to frontend too.
This is working perfect. Then i want to show the image on the backend, if its exist. And i want to reach the frontend.

Thats why i want to set my own aliases in params-local.php file.
But I using vhosts to my webpages and I want to set Aliases to them.
In Yii2 documentation i found an article from aliases, but it wont help me. I mean i tried to use but it wont work.

I tried this:

```
return [
    'aliases' => [
        '@front' => 'http://front.mypage.dev',
        '@back' => 'http://back.mypage.dev',
    ],
];
```

And I also tried this aswell:

```
Yii::setAlias('@front', 'http://front.mypage.dev');
Yii::setAlias('@back', 'http://back.mypage.dev');
```

But when i try to `echo Yii::getAlias('@front');` it sais

```
Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException

Invalid path alias: @front
```

Maybe someone has a solution for this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try setting alias using predefined alias. for ex, `Yii::setAlias('@front', '@fronend/path/to/file');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 Links between Frontend and Backend (advanced template)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206370/yii2-links-between-frontend-and-backend-advanced-template)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in backend/config/params.php like:

```
return [
    'front' => 'http://front.mypage.dev',
    'back' => 'http://back.mypage.dev',
];
```

and use it from:

```
Yii::$app->params['front']
Yii::$app->params['back']
```

Let me know your thought.

Comment: Thanks guys for help, finally i made it with this params solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Yii::setAlias('@front', 'http://front.mypage.dev');
Yii::setAlias('@back', 'http://back.mypage.dev');

echo  Yii::getAlias('@front');
echo  Yii::getAlias('@back');
echo  Yii::getAlias('@frontend/path/to/file');
echo  Yii::getAlias('@backend/path/to/file');
```

[Yii2 Playground](http://www.yiiplayground.com/yii2/web/index.php?r=basics/aliases)
[setting-aliases-in-yii2-within-the-app-config-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797051/setting-aliases-in-yii2-within-the-app-config-file)