# Yii2, on login from frontend redirect to backend?

Tags: yii2

After login from frontend in yii2 I want, page should redirect to backend index page.

```
public function actionLogin()
{     
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
       return $this-> render('commercial');
      }        
    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        $this->layout = 'noBar';
   return $this-> render('home'); //backend/index should be open
    } else {
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I have tried in many ways (like Url manager n all) but did not get the required result?

Comment: same problem facing.

Comment: you want to redirect but you used render. you should to use return $this->redirect(Url::base('http').'/backend/index');

Comment: if you want to use layout, you should redirect to an action in backend then use layout and render page there.

Answer (score 2):

Instead this line:
`return $this-> render('home'); //backend/index should be open`

Write:
`return $this->redirect('https://yoursite.com/backend/site/index');`

Or you can make backendUrlManager in config like : 
[Yii2 Links between Frontend and Backend (advanced template)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206370/yii2-links-between-frontend-and-backend-advanced-template)